# Collection view cell doesn't recognize its outlet

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view controller `ItemCollectionVC`, I want to populate its cells with images, this is how I set it:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    cell.cellImage.image = dataSourceItems[indexPath.row].image
    // Error

    return cell
}
```

> Hoever, there's an error: Value of type `UICollectionViewCell` have no
>   member `cellImage`

The cell is of custom cell `ItemCell`, I set its custom class in story board, and here is `ItemCell`:

```
class ItemCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cellImage: UIImageView!

}
```

I also connected the outlet to the image view of the cell.

So I don't understand why there's an error, anybody knows?

Comment: `let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ItemCell`

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 yeah it worked, thanks!

Comment: @BrightFuture check my answer also work perfectly

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya saw it, thanks!

Comment: @BrightFuture you can also approve my answer and give me vote .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one mistake that you need to define class for cell `as! ItemCell`

```
  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ItemCell
```